# WSAEventSelect, zero event

Tags: windows, winapi, sockets, winsock

In my socket server I use WSAEventSelect() and WSAEnumNetworkEvents() to detect FD_ACCEPT and FD_CLOSE events.

Here is the simplified version of my code:

```
HANDLE sockEv=CreateEvent(NULL,TRUE,FALSE,NULL);
WSAEventSelect(servSocket,sockEv,FD_ACCEPT|FD_CLOSE);
for(;;) {
  if(WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(1,&sockEv,FALSE,INFINITE,FALSE)==WSA_WAIT_EVENT_0) {
    WSANETWORKEVENTS wsaEvents={0};
    WSAEnumNetworkEvents(servSocket,sockEv,&wsaEvents);
    if((wsaEvents.lNetworkEvents & FD_ACCEPT)==FD_ACCEPT) {
      SOCKET clntSock=accept(servSocket,(sockaddr*)clientAddr,&addrlen);
      ....
    }
    else if (wsaEvents.lNetworkEvents==0) {
    // this event occurs after each FD_ACCEPT event
    }
    ....
  }
  ....
}
```

The problem is that each time a new connection is accepted from a client, I receive 2 events: first with WSANETWORKEVENTS.lNetworkEvents set to FD_ACCEP, then with WSANETWORKEVENTS.lNetworkEvents set to zero. That is the for(;;) loop is executed 2 times each time a new client is accepted. Or maybe the sockEv is not reset by WSAEnumNetworkEvents after detecting FD_ACCEPT.

What does this zero event mean and why it happens?
I didn't find anything about it in the documentation.

**UPDATE**: Compilable sample

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  WSADATA wsaData;
  WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsaData);
  try {
    SOCKET servSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);

    sockaddr_in serv={0};
    serv.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serv.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv.sin_port=htons(18081);
    memset(serv.sin_zero,0,sizeof(serv.sin_zero));

    if(bind(servSocket,(sockaddr*)&serv,sizeof(serv))==SOCKET_ERROR)
      throw WSAGetLastError();
    if(listen(servSocket,SOMAXCONN)==SOCKET_ERROR)
      throw WSAGetLastError();
    HANDLE sockEv=CreateEvent(NULL,TRUE,FALSE,NULL);
    if(WSAEventSelect(servSocket,sockEv,FD_ACCEPT|FD_CLOSE)==SOCKET_ERROR) 
      throw WSAGetLastError();

    for(;;) {
      if(WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(1,&sockEv,FALSE,INFINITE,FALSE)!=WSA_WAIT_EVENT_0)
        throw -1;
      WSANETWORKEVENTS wsaEvents={0};
      if(WSAEnumNetworkEvents(servSocket,sockEv,&wsaEvents)==SOCKET_ERROR)
        throw WSAGetLastError();
      if((wsaEvents.lNetworkEvents & FD_ACCEPT)==FD_ACCEPT) {
        SOCKET clntSocket=accept(servSocket,0,0);
        closesocket(clntSocket);
        puts("accept");
      }
      else if(wsaEvents.lNetworkEvents==0) {
        puts("zero event");
      }
    }
  }
  catch(int errorCode) {
    printf("Last Error: %d\n",errorCode);
  }
  WSACleanup();
  return 0;
}
```

I tried this code on WinXP 32bit.

Comment: Put `WSAEventSelect` below `for` line to reselect the event before every wait.

Comment: I've written this loop many times and never seen this behavior as far as I recall.  Is WSAEnumNetworkEvents() succeeding?  What is the rest of your code doing?  Try reducing it down to a minimal sample that we could actually compile and run.

Comment: @Luke I added the compilable sample

Comment: Hmm, it happens for me as well.  Apparently this behavior is widespread; guess I just never noticed before.  Why it's happening, who knows; just ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question. It seems I found why and when this happens. This zero event occurs after the client socket (the socket returned by accept()) is closed. It won't happen if you don't use FD_CLOSE with WSAEventSelect. So one can just ignore it.
MSDN says nothing about this behavior.

Comment: You also have to call WSAResetEvent ( hEvent );

Comment: @chx101 No, you have not.

Comment: @chx101 Yes, it needs to be reset but not necessary using WSAResetEvent(). In my code sample it is reset using WSAEnumNetworkEvents(). Therefore I don't need to call WSAResetEvent

Comment: In your code it's not necessary since it exits after errors. But if you were to get more events you'd need to call WSAResetEvent. That's what the function is there for.

Comment: @TheRealChx101 `WSAEnumNetworkEvents()` resets the event specified in the hEventObject parameter. Read the docs